# NodeJS Sequlize User Registration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I followed a tutorial and tried to implement some code from this repo https://github.com/ArjunAranetaCodes/MoreCodes-Youtube/tree/master/mern-mysql-login-reg. It takes a user's registration information and stores it in a database.

When I put in http://localhost:5000/users/register in postman I get a `Cannot GET /users/register` and I don't know why.

I don't know if its a problem with the database or not. I should be able to reach /users/register though shouldn't I?

**server.js**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const Users = require('./routes/Users');

app.use('/users', Users)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('SERVER RUNNING ON PORT: ' + port);
});
```

**database/db.js**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize("accounts", "root", "password", {
    host: "localhost", 
    dialect: "mysql", 
    operatorAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5, 
        min: 0, 
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }

})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

**models/User.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }, 
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        datetime: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW 
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
)
```

**routes/Users.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors());

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date().toDateString()
    const userData = {
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        name: req.body.name,
        datetime: today
    }

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                userData.password = hash
                User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json({ status: user.email + 'REGISTERED' })
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send('ERROR: ' + err)
                    })
                })
            } else {
                res.json({ error: "USER ALREADY EXISTS" })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('ERROR: ' + err)
        })
})

module.exports = users
```

Comment: the method is defined as POST & maybe you're sending GET request in postman ?

Comment: Yes! That helped alot! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, there is no issue with it. the problem is the method GET you are using in the postman. In your `routes/Users.js` file, note that your registration endpoint only accept `POST`:

```js
users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
})
```

But in the postman you are accessing the route with a `GET` method.
You should select `POST` method and retry. make sure you select json as your model indicate and then select raw for the body.